Which programming language/environment pioneered row-major array order?
The Wikipedia page describing specifics of row-major vs column-major storage order for multi-dimensional arrays, mentions, among others, C/C++ (*1), Pascal and PL/I for the former, and, surely, Fortran for the latter.
Algol-60 is not mentioned. As a matter of fact, the Dijkstra-Zonneveld Algol-60 compiler used column-major ordering.
The rationale could be twofold: to maintain a familiar array layout for those who already worked with Fortran, and to simplify array indexing, as with the column-major order, the multiplier for the first (or the only) array dimension is always the size of an array element, for the second - always the size of the first dimension, etc. which makes it somewhat more convenient for the compiler.
The question therefore is, when and why was the row-major order introduced in languages which had native multi-dimensional array types?
(*1) Strictly speaking, C/C++ must not be present in the list, as they don't have native multi-dimensional array types, and the question of the layout of "array of arrays" is moot.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

LISP 1.5 used row-major order but didn't call it that. I can post an answer later if you think it counts.

@texdr.aft Please do for completeness; however, COBOL is older than LISP.

TL;DR: COBOL
Having said that (see also below), I'm not sure if the examples used are really valid. For one, neither Pascal nor PL/1 define row or column order.
Original 1971 Pascal definition makes in Section 6.2.1 of the original paper no mentioning of order. It also wouldn't make much sense, as indexing is of arbitrary type and range. Thus any access will always have include a correction for the base used before multiplying (or otherwise indexing) any row/column values.
PL/1 in turn does (IIRC) as well not define a storage order (and use ranged index numbering) but an access sequence. That is all operations (calculations, read/write, etc.) acting on arrays at whole (i.e. no indexing given) or sections thereof (i.e. *-notation) will always work element by element, in right to left dimension order and low to high index order(*1). See page 83 of IBM's 1965 manual (*2).

The important point for both languages is that they, by definition, not tell about their storage structure.

To my understanding Algol falls in the same category. AFAIR row/column order was explicit defined as implementation dependent.
C in contrast works complete different by always using zero based numeric indices and explicit handling of arrays as pointers. In section 5.2 the 1978 book states that "Elements are stored in rows,that is, the rightmost subscript varies fastest as elements are accessed in storage order". The fact that multidimensional arrays are arrays of arrays results from that.
Fortran is an outlier as a HLL as, while it also allows based indexing, it does define column-major storage (*3). A fact which I would attribute to its extreme early nature, being still quite machine orientated and not as abstract as (most) later languages.
The same can be said about COBOL - it still falls on a more machine orientated side than a HLL should be - maybe even more than Fortran. Its data structures are not even types of their own, but essentially storage definitions - or records at best - like in Assembler which can be accessed rather arbitrary (*4). If we assume that that indices of a nested table (as they call it) definition are read as (y,x) then COBOL's storage is as much row-major as there can be. See  page 57 of he 1964 OS/360 COBOL Manual for an example using not further structured single byte elements (*5).

So considering that, and the exclusion of C, then the answer may as well be none of the above - unless we talk not language but specific implementation. Of course if COBOL gets included here, then it also makes it the first (after Assembler) with row -major access.

Remarks
HLL and Memory
P.S.: IMHO, defining storage order for data types outside of explicit storage structures (i.e. records) as part of a HLL would be kind of against the whole idea of machine abstraction, wouldn't it?
How Come?
For reasoning why either order is used, I would think that for Fortran really some more valid considerations were made to fit certain assumptions of mathematicians/engineers, while COBOL simply followed what resulted from simply rolling out a repeated nested memory image (*4).
The fact that memory-image lead thinking was standard at the time (due Assembler being THE language) may also explain why Fortran explicit mentions/defines that they are using a different sequence - where COBOL just assumes row-major as 'natural'

*1 - In some way PL/1's data definition is an improved version of what COBOL used. Except unlike COBOL it doesn't guarantee fixed memory relation but leaves that to the compiler, handled (in part) via ALLIGNED and PACKED attributes.
*2 - Thanks to Dave for finding a reference.
*3 - Which can make one easy trip over when passing slices.
*4 - One could argue that this makes C storage wise a COBOL offspring :))
*5 - Serious, COBOL's view of data might look absolute weird for readers grown in today's canon of languages. It doesn't really have variables, but defines memory areas, much like in Assembler. When addressing an element of an array, not the array name is used but the element name, which results in different names used to address the array at whole, a row of an array or an element within. The closest one might describe it is that arrays are always structures and access always done by element. Thus not the array is indexed, like array(index), but the element element(index).
And yes, this also implies that COBOL doesn't know a path like addressing like array.struct.element, but only the element name on it's own. Thus all names are always global, which nicely explains why COBOL field names are so unbelievable chatty.
Don't get me wrong, COBOL is an awesome language, I can see it as kind of first KI language. It took a wile until I learned to love it - right the moment I managed to look behind all the practical bloat countless in house rules for writing COBOL code created. It's a very nice and almost BASIC like language. Easy to learn and great for data handling. Just as much off today's common language pool as FORTH or LISP.


neither Pascal nor PL/1 define row or column order.* Apparently you're wrong about PL/I, see @dave's comment to the question mentioning Page 83


I see no evidence to support the claim that COBOL was storing its multi-dimensional tables in row-major order. Care to adorn your answer with at least one reference?

@LeoB. Dave's comment, the cited page and my answer are all  the same: data is PROCESSED in row-major. The language definition does not define how it's STORED internally. For COBOL: It doesn't know any variable definition like we see them today. It only describes memory, much like assembler, organized as records and subdivisions thereof. An array is simple repetition (name OCCURS n TIMES) of its sub-levels. A multi dimensional array is repeating that with the innermost definition being rolled out first. I'm not really inclined to add a whole course about COBOL's data division.

with the innermost definition being rolled out first Sure enough, but the question is what exactly is "innermost" - the leftmost or the rightmost index.

@LeoB. Don't get me wrong, I'm not keeping COBOL details out to stress you, but because the whole table thing (and data in general) in COBOL is exceptional weird from today's POV. It's opening pandora's box that will end in a 10 page article. It'll need a bit of time to read. Best in its original manuals. For 'Innermost': COBOL records are structured much like PL/1 - in fact, very much like PL/1. So innermost is whatever has the higher level number.

I've found it myself: https://web.archive.org/web/20041216153440/http://www.csis.ul.ie/COBOL/Course/Tables2.htm
around the middle of the page, "A two dimension table".

@LeoB. You may also have a look at the 1964 OS/360 COBOL Manual section 5 p.31..60 DATA DIVISION, especially OCCURS clause (p.57) and Subscripting (p.58), the later containing an example using not further structured single byte elements.

@LeoB. added some refferences.

This is the first time I've seen anyone say something positive about COBOL.

@OmarandLorraine :)) Please note, that comment is about the language and its original design. Not what one sees peeking inti an arbitrary production class COBOL program. I'm still finding new swearwords every time I have to.

The distinction between how an array is processed and how it's stored is language-lawyer quibbling. PL/I was intended to enable the programmer to manipulate the machine's native data representation when necessary. To store the data in a different order would obstruct low level programming. So, we who used PL/I understood that we could, in practice, count on row-major order.

@JohnDoty Erm yes, but no. The point of that question is about language design, not language implementation. And that's exactly the point why IBM guaranteed sequence only for operation, not storage. The storage part is deferred to implementation - which, and there you're right, was usually row-major (At least on /360s where I used it). Also, yes, it's language-lawyering, but that's what the question is all about.

Any implementation of PL/I that didn't use the common understanding that processing and storage order are the same would have been unusable. How would you do binary I/O?

@JohnDoty ??? Not sure what you're trying to say as that's a different area. Same as FP formats or word sizes differ depending on machine. Also, the point is that processing and output sequence or arrays is defined. just not internal storage. Filling an I/O buffer using arrays will result in the same output on every PL/1 implementation .... that is as long as wordsize/datatype is the same.

What if you make an OS call (bypassing language I/O) to do real binary I/O (a common practice)?

@JohnDoty then you're machine specific anyway. Such program will only run on the machine it's written for. Porting to other architectures will be a mess ... as usual. PL/1 was intended to keep that in check.

As a former PL/I programmer, all I can say is yeah, right. Porting to other architectures or dialects was a mess.


The question therefore is, when and why was the row-major order introduced in languages which had native multi-dimensional array types?

I can't answer the "when" offhand, but the "why" question implies there is something complicated or unnatural about row-major order.
English standard reading order itself has the column as the most minor axis of structuring.
The "multi-dimensional array" is jargon to describe what in centuries of everyday clerical practice have typically been called "tables", or "books" (in the accountancy sense of the word).
Indeed the meaning of "column-major" in this context presupposes the existence of the standard "row-major" view of things, against which it defines its differences.
The standard view is one in which a row defines the related fields of a single record, and the fields of a record progress across the column axis. A "column" then means a cross-cut of the same field across many different records/rows, if the data were laid out like a standard table.
In column-major, the meaning of row and column still corresponds to record and field, respectively. And the conceptual hierarchy between these two things, in which a record contains or logically groups its fields (and not the other way around), doesn't change.
Effectively what we're saying is that records are always major and fields are always minor.
What column-major therefore means is not that fields are major. It means the related fields of a record are not co-located in storage. Whereas row-major means they are co-located in storage.
I would argue that the deviation from co-location is the less natural and obvious approach to take.
I don't know which the first language was to use column-major, but the reason why it is used, is to achieve better performance for certain algorithms. This comes at the expense of the performance of certain other algorithms, and it comes at the expense of having an arrangement of data which is conceptually non-standard (as far as clerical workers would tend to conceive things).
Neither approach completely conquers the other, because each is stronger for certain algorithms on certain storage hardware where sequential access is faster than random access.

"Why" implies "why change, if there's already an established way to do it as in Fortran".

A record POV doesn't really match the multi-dimensional array facilities offered in those days.  They were generally used for scientific or other technical computations.  There were some of those where rows did correspond to "records" of some kind, e.g., in linear algebra where you were working with a set of polynomials.  But the main driver of row-major vs column-major would be considerations of the algorithms you would use over those arrays, including pivoting, row elimination, matrix multiply, etc.  IMO, based on my partial recollections of what was going on somewhat before my time.

@LeoB., because for those working on clerical automations rather than mathematical calculations, there wasn't any "change" to row-major. So-called row-major is already how things are done on paper. When you ask someone to fill in a form on a clipboard, you ask them to put their first and last name on one form. You don't hand them two clipboards, one on which they enter their first name, the other on which they enter their last, so that all first names collected are co-located, and all last names collected are co-located, but nobody's full name is co-located on a single page!

@davidbak, I suppose the original question can be interpreted many ways, but talk of things like "pioneering" row-major makes it sound like radical new thinking, hence my answer. From what I understand of the culture in mathematics (which precedes computer technology), column-major is the preferred approach to matrixes there. Hence, I'd guess that Fortran as a maths-oriented language starts with that approach for that reason. But there is a different historical culture in clerical work and amongst those more broadly who use natural language (not just numbers) to represent information.

Observation: when I write code to process an array element-wise, I pretty much always use row-major order: for r ... for c ... do something with a[r,c]; od

@dave, that also illustrates the distinction between two different meanings of row-major. One is a description of how an algorithm proceeds sequentially through each element. The other, which I described, is about the co-location of the elements. You can therefore proceed row-major algorithmically through a column-major array storage-wise.

Implicitly, though (and someone else already made this point) if my way is the obvious way to traverse the array, which I claim it is, then it has better locality-of-reference if the storage is also row-major.  Which is say, I concur that row-major storage is the more natural of the two.  Even without regard to 'record' arguments (which I nevertheless agree with).
